# Rewrite rules with multiple query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

i'm new on htaccess. I'm working on a website with multiple query strings.
I need to rewrite urls of different query strings like:

1. /path_to_website/file.php?product=var1&country=0&pag=1 to /path_to_website/var1/
2. /path_to_website/file.php?product=var1&country=0&pag=var2 to /path_to_website/var1/var2
3. /path_to_website/file.php?product=var1&country=var2&pag=1 to /path_to_website/var1/var2/
4. /path_to_website/file.php?product=var1&country=var2&pag=var3 to /path_to_website/var1/var2/var3

As you can see, the problem is between 2 and 3 rewrite because they have the same number of parameters (if the problem is this). I've done this on htaccess file:

```
###BLOCK 1#######

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /path_to_website/modules/file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=1&rew=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&country=0&pag=1$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$

RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/? [R=301,L]

###BLOCK 2#######

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /path_to_website/modules/file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=$2&rew=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&country=0&(.*)=(.*)$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$

RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/%4/? [R=301,L]

###BLOCK 3#######

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /path_to_website/modules/file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=1&rew=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)&pag=1$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$

RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/%4/? [R=301,L]

###BLOCK 4#######

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /path_to_website/modules/file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=$3&rew=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)&(.*)=(.*)$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$

RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/%4/%6/? [R=301,L]
```

How can I fix this? Because everything works except when I search for product and country !=0 the engine stops on block 2.

Please someone help me because I'm stuck on this problem.

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**

Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for your answer. I tried with your rules, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
############your rule###########
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&country=0&pag=1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /path_to_website/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite with this rules is path_to_website/product/, but the page doesn't work with "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". I tried also with ONLY your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=1 [L]
```

In this case, the rewrite don't work at all, just print the query string. I also tried with the rew=1 key, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /aziende_agrarie/modules/risultato_ricerca.php? 
prodotto=$1&provincia=0&pag=1&rew=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&provincia=0&pag=1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /aziende_agrarie/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite works with path_to_website/product, but when i change the page on 2, the browser url is path_to_website/product/?product=var1&country=0&pag=2. So I insert the rewrite for product/2/, and the rewrite for "file.php?product=var1&country=0&pag=var2" is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(?!=/)$ /aziende_agrarie/modules/risultato_ricerca.php? 
prodotto=$1&provincia=0&pag=$2&rew=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)&provincia=0&(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*rew=1.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /aziende_agrarie/%2/%4/? [R=301,L]
```

An so on. I miss something? Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following Rule sets in your .htaccess file. Also please make sure you clear your cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##For file.php?product=var1&country=0&pag=1
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=1 [L]

##For file.php?product=var1&country=0&pag=var2
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(?!=/)$ file.php?product=$1&country=0&pag=$2 [L]

##For file.php?product=var1&country=var2&pag=1
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=1 [L]

##for file.php?product=var1&country=var2&pag=var3
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ file.php?product=$1&country=$2&pag=$3 [L]
```

**Edit**

I had a GET request with form submit and  href with custom paginator. I solved the problem. The problem was on href because i left the query string like "path_to_website/?product=var1&country=var2&page=1" etc. I resolved this replacing the query string href with "/product/country" for pag1 and so on for the other href. On the submit event, i left my custom block 1 and block 3 rules and for paginator href i wrote your rules for rewrite.